# Media queries not applying

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am ALMOST done with my first project ever and I am applying media queries but I can't see them working completely. I would appreciate some help. Maybe my code for the grid is wrong...

PROBLEM:
The grid-items won't align in 4 columns (media query for min-width 1024px). They will remain in one or two columns according to the code for mobile and media query for ipad screen.

```
<section class="grid-container">

      <div class= "grid-item one">
        <h5>ARTICLE</h5>  
      <a href="#">
          <img src="img/chocolate.png" alt= "Chocolate image"> 
        </a>
        
        <h3>Explore the world of chocolate</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
          Labore eos in deserunt architecto, accusantium quia eaque iste delectus id reiciendis inventore amet possimus! 
          Culpa deleniti nulla dolorem, voluptas minima sapiente. </p>
      </div> 

-----HERE ITEM 2 to 4, I JUMP to the ITEM 5----


      <div class= "grid-item five">
       <h5>TIPS</h5>  
        <a href="#">
          <img src="img/foodmarket.jpg" alt= "Foodmarket image"> 
        </a>
        
        <h3>Best foodmarkets you have to visit</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
          Labore eos in deserunt architecto, accusantium quia eaque iste delectus id reiciendis inventore amet possimus! 
          Culpa deleniti nulla dolorem, voluptas minima sapiente. 
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class= "grid-item six">
       <h5>RECIPE</h5>  
        <a href="#">
          <img src="img/recetamole.png" alt= "Mole dish image"> 
        </a>
        
        <h3>How to make mole from scratch</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
          Labore eos in deserunt architecto, accusantium quia eaque iste delectus id reiciendis inventore amet possimus! 
          Culpa deleniti nulla dolorem, voluptas minima sapiente. 
        </p>
      </div>


    </section>

**/**** MEDIA QUERIES IN CSS ****/**

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  header {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  nav {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: flex-end;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }


  h1 {
    font-size: 42px
  }
  
  p {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%; 
  }
  
  .one, .two {
    grid-column: span 2;
  }

  .three, .four {
    grid-column: span 2;
  }

  .five, .six, {
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
  
  .seven, .eight {
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
 
}
@media (min-width: 1024) {

  .flex-parent {
    flex-direction: row; 
    justify-items: flex-end; 
    
   }

   .flex-child {
     width: 100%;    
   }
   
   .one, .two, .three, .four {
    grid-column: span 1;
  }

   .five, .six, .seven, .eight {
    grid-column: span 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {

  .flex-parent {
    flex-direction: row; 
    justify-items: flex-end; 
    
   }

   .flex-child {
     width: 100%;    
   }
   
   .one, .two, .three, .four {
    grid-column: span 1;
  }

   .five, six, seven, eight {
    grid-column: span 1;
   }
}
```

I think you haven't mention the pixel `@media (min-width: 1024px)`

Add this header part as well as

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you defined `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

And you can even write a full content to be more accurate:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  /*Your changes go here*/
}
```

Remember to put a space bewteen **and** and **(**